# Librosa spectrogram parameters

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, librosa

I want to use Librosa library for creating spectrograms. I want to use librosa.core.stft function for speech processing. They suggest to use parameter n_fft with value of 512 for my case.

What i want to know is what value should i use for other parameters for best results? I mean parameters Like hop_length and window_length?

Answer (score 1):

Well the [librosa-docs](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) explains in details how are these values computed in default and their relation to the sampling rate. Obviously, you can follow their approach or other good practices like the [this-one](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Choice_Hop_Size.html). However, I would say there is no recipe here, the optimal parameters are case dependent.